# How to do a normal functions in python flask without a route and return the results of this process using a route?

Tags: python, flask

The app is loading the "links_submit.html" which has a field where you can write a link, like for example (www.google.com) and you submit it, then the app is receiving this URL as HTTP Post and redirecting to another page "post_response.html" which contains a simple html for feedback with the word "Ok". Then I want to do a process with this link (crawl google and search for a specific thing) and after finish this process, automatically redirect from the "post_reponse.html" to another page to show the results I have extracted from google. Now I'm not sure how say to my app on flask: "Ok now lets use a normal function (not route) like for example:

```
def loadpage(link_sent_by_the_http post):
   res = requests.get('www.google.com')
```

Imagine that after load the page I also extract some html tag on google and after finish this process I want to redirect the page "post_respose.html" with the "ok" to a new html page which contains the html tag extracted from google.
Please note I know how to load the page google and extract what I want, but I don't know how to insert this function/process in the middle of Flask and then redirect from a normal html with "ok" for a new route with the results I have extracted.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def form():
   return render_template('links_submit.html')

@app.route('/links/', methods=['POST'])
def links():
    links=request.form['links']
    return render_template('post_response.html')

Intern Process (Load the received link > Extract what I want)
and then redirect the "post_response.html" to another "html" which will
contain the results that I have extracted) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This cannot be done with flask alone. You'll need JavaScript to implement long polling, or setting up server-sent events or websockets.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do it-

Create a `python` file say `webfunctions.py` and put your function in this file.
e.g. -

```
def inc(x):
    return int(x) + 1
```

Now in your `flask` app file, you can import the whole file or just the function-

```
from webfunctions import inc

@app.route('/whatsnext/', methods=['POST'])
def waiting():
    curVal=request.form['x']
    nextVal = inc(curVal)
    return render_template('post_response.html', nextVal=nextVal)
```

or else, you may declare your definitions at the top of your flask app file. Like below -

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for

def inc(x):
    return int(x) + 1


@app.route('/whatsnext/', methods=['POST'])
def waiting():
    curVal=request.form['x']
    nextVal = inc(curVal)
    return render_template('post_response.html', nextVal=nextVal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer PEJK. I will try it at home, but even doing that still a problem because after I post the links I want to load the html "post_reponse.html" which has a simple "ok" as a feedback that the links were posted and then after load a new page with the results of the process a new "results.html". how can I call other html without need to press any button, will appear "Ok" and when the process is done automatically redirect to new html with the results. The example you send me is sending the Ok and the results in the same page, but I want to send the "ok" first and after the resu

Comment: Strangely, I declare my functions after declaring the route and it still works fine. In that 2nd example, I declare `def inc(x)` after `@app.route('/whatsnext/', methods=['POST'])` and python does not throw any errors.